# iPad wifi connection drop after sometime when sync is on the way

Tags: ios, ipad, synchronization, wifi, ios9

We have one iPad application which fetches data from SQL server using web service. We started that application in 2011. Previously sync was working fine. We did the load testing on iOS 7. We haven't found any issue at that time. But now we are facing issue in Sync. Some times iPad drop the wifi connection and due to that Sync fails. Also `setIdleTimerDisabled:YES` is used just to avoid application to go into sleep mode.

After searching on SO and Apple doc we come to know that to save battery life iOS drops the wifi connection after 30 minutes. If you want persistent wifi connection for your application you need to set

```
<key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
    <true/>
```

in your application .plist file. So according to that we added the same flag in our application. But still we are getting issues in sync. We tested our application on iPad Air 2 having iOS version 9.0, iPad 2 having iOS version 8.4

Please let me know if any one has any solution for the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: both device gives same error(issue) ?

Comment: Yes. I got the error like The network connection was lost. or some time Internet connection appears to be offline.

Comment: And main thing is when I get the error in our application, along with that I get the Sign in Required message of Apple for In app purchase. Means it seems to be issue with the wifi connection

Comment: pooja.. let try below method for Internet Connection Check and try again.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. ```UIRequiresPersistentWiFi``` used to fix it, but now we still get it. I'm totally going bonkers looking for the cause. The WiFi comes back if you put the app in the background and then back in the foreground again. How can we keep it from going out?

Answer (score 0):

## here is the Perfect Solution, might be helpful to you for Check internet Connection.

use this method for internet connection with replace with your and Check again , might be issue will solve .. cheers

```
**in your Appdelegate.m File**

//Check Internet Plugin
#include<unistd.h>
#include<netdb.h>
/////

#pragma mark Check Internet connection
-(BOOL)checkInternetConnection {
    
    char *hostname;
    struct hostent *hostinfo;
    hostname = "google.com";
    hostinfo = gethostbyname (hostname);
    if (hostinfo == NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"-> no connection!\n");
        return NO;
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"-> connection established!\n");
        return YES;
    }
}
```

**try above Code, it working fine and perfect**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But we are not checking internet connection. We just send request to web service using NSURLConnection and wait for the response. But when WIFI drops it call the didfailwitherror delegate function due to which I get the error.

Comment: i got your point. but i think you have to manage it when Wifi is connected/Disconnected. you have to check that how many data is pending to upload, and send it when Wifi is available. simple do that. got it ? is that good idea ?